# How do I stop receiving everything from Allah so that I don't have to be grateful?

Tags: allah, islamic-philosophy, punishment, jahannam

It's unlikely for me to completely enter into Islam. Also I need to be saved from fire and  horrible Angels of punishment hereafter. So I urgently need to stop receiving everything from Allah so that I don't have to be grateful or accountable for anything. What's the way to get out of these?

Comment: Not being grateful itself is kufr. So you want to move from bad to worse?

Answer (score 2):

What are you even talking about? Allah even owns you! everything you eat, everything you use somehow goes back to Allah. And i also agree with you that we can never return the favors of Allah.

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Do good deeds properly, sincerely and
> moderately, and receive good news because **one's good deeds will not
> make him enter Paradise.**" They asked, "Even you, O Allah's Messenger
> (ﷺ)?" He said, "**Even I, unless and until Allah bestows His pardon
> and Mercy on me.**"

No one will enter paradise with their deeds but with the Mercy of Allah, Because our deeds will never be enough. So to get the mercy of Allah, Try your best to obey him, ask for forgiveness and be Grateful. **He has the right to punish us but he choose to forgive and show us mercy.**

Answer (score 1):

Assalamu Alaikum brother/sister,

Stop receiving all blessings also means not being blessed with the ability to eat, drink, breath, see, listen, move, feel happiness(depression is a thing) or being muslim.

'And if you count all the blessings of Allah, never will you be able to count them.' (Surah Ibrahim 14:34)

Living without the blessings of Allah is impossible. We should instead actively search for the blessings and be grateful for them so that we will be rewarded for it in the hereafter and receive even more blessings in our current life. And overall become positive and optimistic people.

'If you are grateful I will surely give you more and more.'(Surah Ibrahim 14:7)

One of the easiest ways to show grattitude and earn rewards for the hereafter is performing dhikr. Just simply say Alhamdulillah when something good happens, or saying it twice once something doesn't happen because Allah is the best of planner, and he has a better plan for you.

https://productivemuslim.com/alhamdulillah-one-word-countless-blessings/

I am a revert Alhamdullilah and suprisingly I am just as many other reverts much happier and content now than in our jahiliyya period, even though we were able to do more things before, and are now obligated to do certain things.

I see the orders of Allah more as protection, prevention and beneficent rather than solely restriction. Allahs order things not simply to pest us. They often have a reason that we currently or in the future know off whether dunya or akhira.
Starting from something as small as not lying on your stomach has recently been backed by science to be harmfull.
Or fasting and performing tahnik has recently scientifically been proven to be highly beneficial as well.

Anyway brother/sister following the commands of Allah doesn't necessarily mean you can't do fun things and enjoy life. It merely functions as a boundaries to protect you from possible harms. We can work on our hapiness in both the akhira AND dunya.

May Allah make it easy for all of us, and guide us, ameen.

Allah knows best.

Comment: Jazakumul llahu kharan, we really appreciate your contribution, please help us develope our dream society, you may visit [tour] for more information

Answer (score 0):

If you say there is no god but  allah and that Muhammad and Jesus are messengers of God
, then you will not stay in Hell forever, but rather you will enter it and then leave it to Heaven.
But you should not do anything of disbelief, such as denying the obligation to pray.

> Abu Sa'id al-Khudri reported: Verily the Messenger of Allah (may peace be upon him) said: Allah will admit into Paradise those deserving of Paradise, and He will admit whom He wishes out of His Mercy, and admit those condemned to Hell into the Fire (of Hell). He would then say: See, he whom you find having as much faith in his heart as a grain of mustard, bring him out. They will then be brought out burned and turned to charcoal, and would be cast into the river of life, and they would sprout aj does a seed in the silt carried away by flood. Have you not seen that it comes out yellow (fresh) and intertwined ?

Comment: Jazakumul llahu kharan, we really appreciate your contribution, please help us in developing our dream community, please visit [tour] for more information, Assalamualaikum waramatullahi wabarakatuhu